# Wrong optimization with scipy (maximize)

Tags: python, function, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to use [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) to identify the optimal values for 3 parameters(variable). I am starting with a very simple optimization function that sums the analyzed parameters together with some predefined (past) values. The values are bound using some fixed values. I set the value of the `sign` parameter to `-1` as I am dealing with a maximization problem. However, scipy returns `[0, 0, 0]` as optimal values (same as setting `sign=1`), while the correct solution is `[2, 2, 2]`. Am I setting something wrong? What am I missing?

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

old = [1,1,1]

def f(params,sign=-1.0):
    first, second, third = params
    return sum(old+[first, second, third])

initial_guess = [2,2,2]

in1 = 1
in2 = 2
in3 = 1

bnds = ((0, in1+2), (0, in2+2), (0, in3+2))
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess, bounds=bnds)

print result.x
```

Comment: You don't use `sign` in `f`. Is it intentional?

Comment: Where should I use it then?

Comment: Multiply it with the sum you return

Comment: `[0, 0, 0]` _is_ the correct solution if you're doing a minimization (which you are). `old` is a constant, so the minimum will be found for the lower bounds of `first`, `second` and `third`, which are all zero. I think @AndreySobolev is right and you meant to multiply the return value of `f` with -1.

Comment: For some reasons I thought that it was directly used by optimize.minimize. It does make sense to multiply the return value! (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

In general when performing nonlinear optimization, libraries like your function to take only a single parameter vector.  A good idea, generally, if you want to maximize a function is to minimize its inverse.  If you simply want to maximize the value of `x1+x2+x3`, I would write things out this way:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return 1/sum(x)

guess = [2,2,2]
x1bnds = (0, 3)
x2bnds = (0, 4)
x3bnds = (0, 5)
bnds = (x1bnds, x2bnds, x3bnds)
result = minimize(f, guess, bounds=bnds)
```

`print(result.x)` will give you `[3,4,5]` because the optimizer hit the bounds.

If you want to operate on the distance between your input parameters and some other values, I would modify the setup as so:

```
from functools import partial
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

other_values = np.asarray([3,4,5])
def f(x, other_pts):
    x_lcl = np.asarray(x)
    difference = x_lcl-other_pts
    return 1/difference.sum()

guess = [2,2,2]
x1bnds = (0, 3)
x2bnds = (0, 4)
x3bnds = (0, 5)
bnds = (x1bnds, x2bnds, x3bnds)
f_opt = partial(f, other_values)
result = minimize(f_opt, guess, bounds=bnds)
```

`print(result.x)` will give you `[0,0,0]` because the optimizer hit the bounds.

It is a good idea to make the function you optimize not depend on external data (globals) -- using a `partial` will make everything a little nicer.

If you don't want to use numpy, you could use a list comprehension to do the elementwise subtraction of x and the other parameter vector, but this way things are a little nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I struggle to see the advantage on using partial. Is it only a "style" reason (clean code)?

Comment: @Lazza87 many of these algorithms are implemented in C/C++/Fortran.  If you use external variables, the optimizer will have to constantly walk the line between C and Python, which is a slow process, to access them.  If you provide them upfront as either local function variables or part of a partial object, your optimization will run much faster.  There is also advantage in distributed computing, since you can pickle a Partial, but you'd be SOL with globals.

Comment: @Lazza87 you may also prefer the `mystic` package (on PyPI) for constrained optimization, its setup is a bit better for more complicated constraints.